# Problem in sorting a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to put in order a column of a dataframe using the following step

`data_crian = data_crian.sort_values(by = 'Flp_CO')`

But I get this message everytime I try to run it:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Does anyone know why?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's causing the issue?

Comment: Well, i think so! The problem was in the data type, it was possible to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple csv file with one column:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'data.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

sorted_data = data.sort_values(by='Numbers')
print(sorted_data)
```

And this is the output:

```
   Numbers
0        1
3        4
7        7
4        8
1       12
6       15
2       32
5       73
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I think i had a problem because of the data type. But now it is solve it.

Comment: @JuliaMoore Please vote up and check the answer if it was helpful. Thanks.